# Function is not defined, Ionic (latest version)

Tags: html, typescript, function, onclick, ionic4

```
<ion-icon id= "list" name="list-sharp" onclick = "appear()"></ion-icon>
<ion-card id = "popup">
//other stuff
</ion-card>

appear(){
document.getElementById("popup").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

The first part is in html the appear method is in typescript, and whenever i click on my list icon it gives me an error and says appear is not defined, anyone know why this is.

Comment: you missed the function keyword in front of appear(){}

Comment: @AmirAhmed you dont have to add the function keyword in typescript